# Python unexpected import behaviour

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-import

I am trying to build a view where forms are loaded dynamically based on the form slug, the available forms are defined in a list of tuples like this, this is meant to speed up development of new forms in a "framework-like" way:

```
#installed_io.py
forms = [("json",JsonForm),("csv",CsvForm),....]
```

froms are defined in the forms.py module as usual.

```
from django import forms

class FileForm(BaseDatasetForm):
    file = forms.FileField(label="Opcion 1: Seleccione un archivo", required=False)
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label="Opction 2: Introduzca el contenido en este campo", required=False)
```

utils.py defines the function to dynamically select the Form class:

```
from installed_io import installed_inputs    

def get_input_form(slug):
    for entry in installed_inputs:
        if entry[0] == slug:
            return entry[1]
    raise NotImplementedError("The required form is not implemented or missing from the installed inputs")
```

The view is defined in the views.py module of my django app:

```
#views.py
from utils import get_input_form

@login_required
def add(request, slug):
    InputForm = get_input_form(slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InputForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            object_id = form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Dataset created")
            return redirect(reverse("input:dataset", args=[str(object_id.inserted_id)]))
    else:
        form = InputForm()
    return render(request, "datasets/add-form.html", {"form":form})
```

but I'm getting this import error:

```
python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fe9c465c398>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jesus/workspace/tensorflow-board-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jesus/workspace/tensorflow-board-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/jesus/workspace/tensorflow-board-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/jesus/workspace/tensorflow-board-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jesus/workspace/tensorflow-board-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/jesus/workspace/tensorflow-board-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/jesus/workspace/tensorflow-board-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/jesus/workspace/tensorflow-board-django/tensorflow_board_django/analysis/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..input.forms import SOURCES
  File "/home/jesus/workspace/tensorflow-board-django/tensorflow_board_django/input/forms.py", line 2, in <module>
    from utils import save_dataset
  File "/home/jesus/workspace/tensorflow-board-django/tensorflow_board_django/input/utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    from installed_io import installed_inputs
  File "/home/jesus/workspace/tensorflow-board-django/tensorflow_board_django/input/installed_io.py", line 1, in <module>
    from forms import FileForm
ImportError: cannot import name FileForm
```

What I've tried:

- Changing the import statements using absolute paths
- Deleting pyc files
- Using dot notation to import modules
- Trying to save the installed_input list on **init**.py
- **Only moving all the code to the views.py file worked**, but I find this solution to be very monolithic and non-pythonic.

Comment: I'm seeing a circular import in your stack trace, going `forms -> utils -> installed_io -> forms`. Those cause all sorts of initialization order headaches, probably including the problem you're seeing here. Avoid them if at all possible.

Comment: That smells `circular import` or an error within FileForm itself. Try to run the shell `./manage.py shell` and `from .. import FileForm` to make sure that one works independently. Then try `from utils import get_input_form` in your shell.

Comment: manage.py shell will throw the same exception, merging both utils.py and installed_io.py into views.py does solve the import problem.

Comment: You can do an input within a closure (within a function call) to test, although I recommend re-writing your imports to avoid any circular imports in the long run.

Comment: if you wish, post a response for this answer with the best way to solve this kind of circular dependency, otherwise I will post my solution later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments on the original post I made the following changes to my code:

instead of importing classes on installed_io module I used strings:

```
#installed_io.py
forms = [("json","JsonForm"),("csv","CsvForm"),....]
```

then I changed utils.py to import the class from string:

```
from installed_io import installed_inputs    

def get_input_form(slug):
    for entry in installed_inputs:
        if entry[0] == slug:
            module = importlib.import_module("tensorflow_board_django.io.forms")
            class_name = entry[1]
            return getattr(module, class_name)
    raise NotImplementedError("The required form is not implemented or missing from the installed inputs")
```